How can I automatically save my renders with incremental filenames in Blender?
I’m working on a project where I’d like to keep track of my renders by saving them with filenames like 000.jpg, 001.jpg, and so on. It would be really handy if each time I hit F12 to render, the composited result would automatically be saved with the next number in the sequence.
I’ve tried using the File Output node with a driver linked to a scene custom property, but I haven’t had much luck with that approach. I’d prefer not to use a script if possible, since it means making another addon I need to keep track of.
Is there an easier way to set up Blender so that it automatically saves each render I do with an incremental filename? Because I keep doing that manually. Or, if scripting is the only way, what’s the simplest approach to achieve this?

I think an add-on or a script is the only way.
You could simply run a script that registers some app handler:
bl_info = {
    "name": "Auto Name Still Render",
    "author": "Martynas Žiemys",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (4, 1, 0),
    "location": "...",
    "description": "Names Render Output",
    "category": "Render",
}

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent
from os import path

@persistent
def render_filename(scene):
    out_path = path.splitext(scene.render.filepath)[0]
    if out_path[-4:].isnumeric():
        out_path = out_path[:-4] + str(int(out_path[-4:])+1).zfill(4)
    else:
        out_path = out_path + " 0001"
    scene.render.filepath = out_path

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(render_filename)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.remove(render_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

I added the add-on bits in case you want to install as an add-on. You could check for some specific characters like #### for it to activate so it doesn't interfere with the cases where you don't want this functionality.
I also assume that you have enabled Write Image for your  F12  hotkey in the preferences so the still renders are saved automatically when you hit  F12 :


I would suggest bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.remove(render_filename) instead of bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.clear() to avoid removing handlers that have not been registered by this addon
